# How would I be able to use the Emmet tag "!" in Djang-html?

Tags: html, django, emmet

I know that to fix the emmet abbreviations for most tags for Django-html is by going to *preferences* ---> *settings* ---> *Emmet*. After getting there I proceeded to add (Django-html, html) into the item and value area. After doing so I am able to use normal emmet abbreviations but I want to use the "!" tag. is there a reason why I cannot use it or is there a fix needed.

Thank y'all in advance.

Answer (score 0):

go to **settings** or press **Ctrl+,** ->**Extension** -> **Emmet**

you want to use the Tab key for expanding the Emmet abbreviations, add the following setting in **vscode**:

```
"emmet.triggerExpansionOnTab": true
```

and `Show Expanded Abbreviation`

make it to `always`

this link is useful [emmet](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/emmet) for vscode

hopefully that is help you